# Eclipse build errors are coming from out-of-date code

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I'm running Eclipse 3.7.2 with CDT installed on Ubuntu 12.04.

I created a new C++ project, then added existing source/header files by drag and dropping them into the project explorer. I added the header include paths and source paths to the project settings. The source code I added had a few compiler errors that I fixed. Simple stuff.

**My Problem:**

For lack of a better explanation, the build error log is showing "ghost" errors; errors that *used* to exist, but just aren't there anymore. Here's a screenshot showing where it's claiming the errors are in my code. ***Note:*** Image is high-resolution. View in separate tab so you can read it!

[image: some code and corresponding "errors"]

As you can see, it's complaining about a multiple definition error on line 24. And the code on line 24 has nothing to do with such claims.

Running clean on the project does nothing to help this issue.

Here's the console output for the build.

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project blitzAPI ****

make -k all 
Building target: blitzAPI
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "blitzAPI"  ./src/blitzAPI.o ./src/function.o ./src/iohelper.o ./src/main.o ./src/strHelper.o   
./src/main.o: In function `parseTree(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
/home/david/workspace/blitzAPI/Debug/../src/main.cpp:24: multiple definition of `verbose'
./src/blitzAPI.o:/home/david/workspace/blitzAPI/Debug/../src/blitzAPI.cpp:48: first defined here
./src/main.o: In function `parseTree(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
/home/david/workspace/blitzAPI/Debug/../src/main.cpp:24: multiple definition of `lineCount'
./src/blitzAPI.o:/home/david/workspace/blitzAPI/Debug/../src/blitzAPI.cpp:48: first defined here
./src/main.o: In function `parseTree(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
/home/david/workspace/blitzAPI/Debug/../src/main.cpp:24: multiple definition of `functionList'
./src/blitzAPI.o:/home/david/workspace/blitzAPI/Debug/../src/blitzAPI.cpp:51: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blitzAPI] Error 1
make: Target `all' not remade because of errors.

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: Haven't used Eclipse CDT, but have you tried doing a clean build?

Comment: As in using Project Menu > Clean... ? Yes, to no effect. If you mean starting the project over and adding source source by hand, then I haven't done that. That's what I'm going to do while I'm awaiting an answer on this question. Even so, this has me befuddled.

Comment: Actually now I see these are linker errors. Are you sure you don't actually have duplicate definitions of symbols in more than one file? The code may be correct in each file, but if you have a non-static function with the same name in more than one file, it's breaking the One Definition Rule.